# Nginx match rails assets which have md5 hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, md5, sprockets

My rails application has some files which are excluded from the rails asset pipeline so do not have an md5 hash in the name of the file. But i want to add a max-age header of 1y for all the assets that are precompiled by sprockets. How can i selectively just set max-age header only on the assets which were precompiled by sprockets.

One thing i have in mind is that since md5 hash is always 33 characters ( i tested it by checking the lengths of the hashes ), maybe i can have a regex which matches 33 characters after the dash in the file name. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Other ideas?

Following are the example file names.

```
application-cb61c25ef6120a3100f6c5774c26e2ad.js  
application-cb61c25ef6120a3100f6c5774c26e2ad.js.gz  
arrows-df2013a3aca5b91d70cf0aac7a5d6994.png  
ip-icon-731b22bd05d1c61d4f0074e69f942707.png
```

**Edit:**
I came up with something like below for nginx conf:

```
location ~ ^/assets/.+-[0-9a-f]{32}\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|woff|ttf|eot|map)(.gz)? {
  expires 1y;
  add_header Cache-Control public;

  add_header ETag "";
  break;
}
```

Comment: The md5 hash is also made up of 0-9a-f.  So you could match on "*-[33charsofmd5]\." and that should do it.  No idea how efficient that is though.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipHallstrom I came up with http://rubular.com/r/zqX9Ax4rod . Comments?

Comment: Implemented your suggestion here http://rubular.com/r/gtu2uMTPls

Comment: Why limit it to jss/png?  http://rubular.com/r/FINuF2TWyj  Wouldn't that also work and pick up CSS/JPG as well?

Comment: Nginx complained about the `{` so i added a `\` infront of it. But its not setting the max-age to 1y :(

Comment: I took CSS/JPG just as an example. The `{32}` thing does not seem to be working for nginx. It is failing to match when i put the escape `\\`

Comment: Nginx might not support {}.  I don't know.  You could try http://rubular.com/r/JNq8YN1Fu8  .  Might be too aggressive though.

Comment: Adding double quotes around the regex worked. So, i finally have `location ~ "^/assets/.+-([0-9a-f]){32}\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|woff|ttf|eot|map)(\.gz)?"`